# How to exclude sting. int, double, bool and other class's short names from Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible? I want to use full class names. Hate to see dark blue color of class names.

Comment: They are *keywords* in the language you use, not class names.  So they get the color that's used for keywords, dark blue.  You don't have to use keywords, you could use their actual class names like String, Boolean, Int32.  You'd better discuss that with your team mates first :)

Comment: Hans, I know all this (:  And I want to exclude this keywords from intellisense. I want to type bool, hit ctrl+space and get Boolean, not bool.